# Extending a function that gives a value to convex functions to a measure

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am wondering if such a result exists (or similar) and or if there is a "simple" proof.

Let $\mathcal X$ be a bounded and closed subset of a topological vector space, let $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra associated and let $\Gamma$ be the set of bounded convex continuous function on $\mathcal X$, suppose that the topology on $\mathcal X$ is the weakest topology such that all functions in $\Gamma$ are continuous. Suppose we have $\mu:\Gamma\to\mathbb R$ that is such that
\begin{align*}
\mu(1)&=1\\
\forall f,g\in\Gamma \text{ such that }f\leq g,~~~\mu(f)&\leq \mu(g)\\
\sum_{i\in\mathcal I}a_i\mu(f_i) &=\mu\left( f \right)
\end{align*}
Whenever $\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} a_i f_i=f\in\Gamma$ for $f_i$ in $\Gamma$, $a_i \geq 0$ and $\mathcal I$ some countable set. Here $\left(\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} a_i f_i\right) (x)=\sup\left\{ \sum_{j\in \mathcal J} a_j f_j(x) : \mathcal J\subseteq \mathcal I,|\mathcal J|<\infty\right\}$

> There exists a unique probability measure $\mu:\Sigma\to\mathbb R$ such that when seen as a function from $\Gamma$ to $\mathbb R$ through Lebesgue integration, $\mu$ matches with the previous function.

The reason why I think this may be true is that it is known that the Choquet ordering is a partial order on a convex closed bounded set (see Definition 2.9 and Proposition 2.10 in [this](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123600X03199/1-s2.0-0022123676900732/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEG4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICZf8MIOP5LIMdjOjvL%2FK957VerQ7zD4tkfQLLXodpYAAiEArLkFsauDBVn9irczzz6X4NT83XqRpxXYH9H0uHMVv9Mq0gQIVhAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDLtotLtQQAEl76WnoiqvBNK8xVTycXySTrhH0DI5CqwV5EkPQc8J%2FP3TkLZW42TLBnT2tc1fOhY1znOSmYTcuVmXDgRoVnvQV0EFVfQGN7%2FULB5u7QpShU3hiVdEG1%2BZh6tFLgwLHtWS6z6ugA%2FTeUxQqcHnIzDLPnM%2F%2Bcr81VKHZkWuGtvigGCOmzzaP%2BPXzx%2FGun%2FNML2Ma7bIYJGIpW%2BLeSG5q48CXP7VlDzVKG24cPVFbXsKbM0uV4YELP1emzqhrPrm7AA8x0oJANn70QWRRgofBHESxrCPPSNK11oXobhWeZLHOxNFdS1nY%2BUSIuRsaX3vSwfAGJyXv5FzMPczsGGupahDZZ4GMZ2InEYwrXvvEAGGlr%2BF3bUdLv3X%2FVq5HsQ%2FJYXJQm6mdCXY3Bd7I3llxFKguPgZlq%2BFsfJgTEQanlykGP5r0KdXb6K4G7Hmg%2Fy%2BQjTz26vEtvYKeIjhcqsONtqy3KY74DYiAbeafk6j9BDoUruF47lhtwPg%2Fc%2B50nXG0n9NzaMd6aqVQhTkYMKplQtsNjv9mkveZJSZpNUAQfml1h0lLDBtLTjPl7Jii5xRJZ2PdWGWbMbfZhGbkpOAFPdSKRv5f4HHdJZyaZ6o6pxDTyhbZdf380GB%2FEhYZKFqII6tHJ84h4X58LGxgFny%2FEoXGkDYw1HtWsPgdB4RQQNekwNg5WiWQ%2F8XP56yaxOno4n5pKLWxNqS4s6UxZVOLUA2SBXET9Tk5tvGv30ZV%2BlLFxyddMcQ0oAw2ayslAY6qQHyzrYj5pdLQosNK6ckEUuNwEkYZqyw3NKucFWXFBBbfvFteG%2Fb2QLqDyOAyJrgs%2BR9rygZL9AaVH7tnas7hBM91vdZjRcATaHbon3AG61PJ5QbxN%2Bf0zQBzDQY%2BRytPEYVeoU9Hupc4SJMV%2FBJZ%2BDV7BgietHCWBbhSc0BT8uhaEyWlN4gwYYV3wiguCvwgCk8tpJvbUUWzvCG2klNu4xb3VtDZcazt%2BST&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220523T064226Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSTCB7QOL%2F20220523%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=f2be1daf84dea1722d27e8c86dee583beeb276ace3c8e7363b07f1884fcd38a7&hash=a2a578cfdc7d0baa691fc84b95ea19e2b7eb3ea1af584a60e62b9b74e55ff19f&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0022123676900732&tid=spdf-c11caadf-0826-47c8-967c-5a852b593d80&sid=8c6e2acd4e3b734fb47914957add46e49038gxrqb&type=client&ua=54510806010405565e&rr=70fbcfc40b813b51)), this would give uniqueness so I think we have to argue about existence. We may need to add extra assumption, my goal here is to try to find necessary and sufficient condition for extitence of such a probability measure.

---

Maybe one way to go would be to try to use Caratheodory's extension theorem on a pre-measure that we define on the topology of $\mathcal X$. For instance I am thinking that it could be that for a closed set $A$, $\mu(A)=\inf\{ \mu(f)-\mu(g) : f,g\in\Gamma ~s.t.~f-g\geq \mathbf 1_A  \}$ where $\mathbf 1_A$ denotes the indicator function of $A$. If this is a good candidate (maybe we have to change into $\inf$) then we can define the measure on open sets $A$ as $\mu(A)=1-\mu(A^c)$ and then extend this pre-measure to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra using Caratheodory's extension theorem. We then have to show that this measure integrates to the right value on $\Gamma$ and conclude using Proposition 2.10 of the previous [document](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123600X03199/1-s2.0-0022123676900732/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEG4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICZf8MIOP5LIMdjOjvL%2FK957VerQ7zD4tkfQLLXodpYAAiEArLkFsauDBVn9irczzz6X4NT83XqRpxXYH9H0uHMVv9Mq0gQIVhAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDLtotLtQQAEl76WnoiqvBNK8xVTycXySTrhH0DI5CqwV5EkPQc8J%2FP3TkLZW42TLBnT2tc1fOhY1znOSmYTcuVmXDgRoVnvQV0EFVfQGN7%2FULB5u7QpShU3hiVdEG1%2BZh6tFLgwLHtWS6z6ugA%2FTeUxQqcHnIzDLPnM%2F%2Bcr81VKHZkWuGtvigGCOmzzaP%2BPXzx%2FGun%2FNML2Ma7bIYJGIpW%2BLeSG5q48CXP7VlDzVKG24cPVFbXsKbM0uV4YELP1emzqhrPrm7AA8x0oJANn70QWRRgofBHESxrCPPSNK11oXobhWeZLHOxNFdS1nY%2BUSIuRsaX3vSwfAGJyXv5FzMPczsGGupahDZZ4GMZ2InEYwrXvvEAGGlr%2BF3bUdLv3X%2FVq5HsQ%2FJYXJQm6mdCXY3Bd7I3llxFKguPgZlq%2BFsfJgTEQanlykGP5r0KdXb6K4G7Hmg%2Fy%2BQjTz26vEtvYKeIjhcqsONtqy3KY74DYiAbeafk6j9BDoUruF47lhtwPg%2Fc%2B50nXG0n9NzaMd6aqVQhTkYMKplQtsNjv9mkveZJSZpNUAQfml1h0lLDBtLTjPl7Jii5xRJZ2PdWGWbMbfZhGbkpOAFPdSKRv5f4HHdJZyaZ6o6pxDTyhbZdf380GB%2FEhYZKFqII6tHJ84h4X58LGxgFny%2FEoXGkDYw1HtWsPgdB4RQQNekwNg5WiWQ%2F8XP56yaxOno4n5pKLWxNqS4s6UxZVOLUA2SBXET9Tk5tvGv30ZV%2BlLFxyddMcQ0oAw2ayslAY6qQHyzrYj5pdLQosNK6ckEUuNwEkYZqyw3NKucFWXFBBbfvFteG%2Fb2QLqDyOAyJrgs%2BR9rygZL9AaVH7tnas7hBM91vdZjRcATaHbon3AG61PJ5QbxN%2Bf0zQBzDQY%2BRytPEYVeoU9Hupc4SJMV%2FBJZ%2BDV7BgietHCWBbhSc0BT8uhaEyWlN4gwYYV3wiguCvwgCk8tpJvbUUWzvCG2klNu4xb3VtDZcazt%2BST&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220523T064226Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSTCB7QOL%2F20220523%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=f2be1daf84dea1722d27e8c86dee583beeb276ace3c8e7363b07f1884fcd38a7&hash=a2a578cfdc7d0baa691fc84b95ea19e2b7eb3ea1af584a60e62b9b74e55ff19f&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0022123676900732&tid=spdf-c11caadf-0826-47c8-967c-5a852b593d80&sid=8c6e2acd4e3b734fb47914957add46e49038gxrqb&type=client&ua=54510806010405565e&rr=70fbcfc40b813b51).

---

An argument proposed by @gerw is that we can extend $\mu$ to be a linear functional on the closure of $\Gamma-\Gamma$ which may match with the set of measurable functions (or at least contain all $1_A$ for $A$ open or close) and then by the Riesz representation theorem there is a probability measure that represents that functional.

---

I added the condition that if $f\leq g$ are in $\Gamma$, then $\mu(f)\leq \mu(g)$. this will indeed be true if $\mu$ comes from a probability measure and it is possible to build values for $\mu(f)$ for any $f\in\Gamma$ such that the other two axioms are satisfied but not this one. An example is when $\mathcal X=[0,1]$, then all convex function are countable sums of the functions of the type $h_p:x\to |x-p|$ and adding the $1$ function, but if we fix any probability measure $\mu$ and take the mapping $\mu:\Gamma \to \mathbb R$ and define it to be the same on $h_p$ except for instance for $h_{1/2}$ then extend the values to $\Gamma$ linearly, we have $\mu(1)=1$ and $\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} a_i \mu(f_i)=\mu(f)$ but for sure there is no probability measure.

Comment: I think that you need some kind of continuity of $\mu$ (note that your third condition only gives positive homogeneity w.r.t. rational numbers). Otherwise, you could have, e.g., $\mu(\pi) = \mathrm{e}$...

Comment: @gerw Yes you are right, I also think that I need to state that the topology of $\mathcal X$ is the weakest such that all element of $\Gamma$ are continuous. What topology on measures do you think could do the trick ? And otherwise does the whole thing seem crazy ? Is it related to some known result ? It feels like it would exist somewhere if true. Also I think that another way to solve the problem you mention is to allow the sum in my last axiom to be any sum, as long as it exists, similarly we need the sum of $f_i$ to exists. In that case I think it takes care of the fact that $\mu(x)=x$ .

Comment: My thoughts were the following: I think that your assumptions on $\mu$ should allow to extend $\mu$ to a functional on the set of functions, which are the difference of two convex functions (DC). On (bounded, convex subsets of) $\mathbb R^n$, the DC functions should be dense in the continuous functions. Thus, you can extend $\mu$ to a functional on the continuous functions by continuity (to be assumed). Finally, this is a measure by the Riesz representation theorem. I am not sure whether this line of reasoning can be generalized to topological vector spaces...

Comment: @gerw Using Riesz representations theorem is a very nice idea. I'm actually wondering about the following, for a closed set $A$, $1_A$ is upper semi-continuous. If we look at $h=\inf\{ f-g : f,g\in\Gamma, f-g\geq 1_A\}$, it is also upper semi-continuous. If we can show that we actuallly have $h=1_A$ then we can basically give probability to all closed set and might be able to extend, or maybe we can actually generate all bounded upper semi-continuous function in that way, not just indicator and then use Riesz.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt when $\mathcal X$ is compact, in order to generalize to closed and bounded, the only details missing are to show that $f'$ (see definition below) is continuous whenever $f$ is continuous and bounded as well as the fact that [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) doesn't apply (there may be a generalization which I am not aware of). All of this is probably very related to order dual and order bound, not sure if there is a way to express it in this framework. Any improvement of this answer or other answer would be most appreciated.

We can extend $\mu:\Gamma\to\mathbb R$ to $\mu:\Gamma-\Gamma\to\mathbb R$ trivially as $\mu(f_1-f_2)=\mu(f_1)-\mu(f_2)$. Now the function is linear (and even countably linear) and satisfy $\mu(f)\geq 0$ for all $f\in\Gamma-\Gamma$ such that $f\geq 0$. Of course we still have $\mu(1)=1$.

The next step is to extend $\mu:C_c(\mathcal X)\to\mathbb R$, we can do this by using [Hahn-Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) (here the sublinear function we use is important later on to prove we have a probability distribution), It is clear that $\Gamma-\Gamma$ is a subspace of $C_c(\mathcal X)$ and we can use the sublinear function $p:f\to \mu(f')$ where $f'(p)=\sup \{ \nu(f):\nu\sim x \}$ where the supremum is taken over all Radon measure that averages to $x$ in the sense of the Bochner integral. This function is clear concave (it is actually the concave envellope on compact sets) and I think it should be continuous but couldn't prove it (if any one knows how to do that I would really appreciate it). The thing is that $p$ is really defined on $C_c(\mathcal X)$ and is sublinear such that $\mu(f)\leq p(f)$ for any $f\in\Gamma-\Gamma$ (because $f\leq f'$). Applying the Hahn-Banach theorem gives us a linear function $\mu:C_c(\mathcal X)\to\mathbb R$  such that it matches with the previous one on $\Gamma-\Gamma$ and $\mu\leq p$. If $f\in C_c(\mathcal X)$ is such that $-f\geq 0$, then $\mu(f')= p(f)\geq \mu(f)$ but clearly $f'\leq 0$ since $f\leq 0$ and so $f\geq 0$ implies $\mu(f)\geq$. By [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) we get a a unique positive Radon measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal X$ such that $\nu(f)=\mu(f)$ for all $f\in C_c(\mathcal X)$, but we still have that $\nu(1)=\mu(1)=1$ and so this is our final goal.