# Space of difference of continuous convex functions is dense in continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, convex-analysis, boolean-algebra

Let $X$ be a bounded closed convex subset of a locally convex space $E$. Let $\Gamma(X)$ be the set of continuous convex functionals on $X$ and let $C(X)$ be the set of continuous functionals.

> Is $\Gamma(X)-\Gamma(X)$ dense in $C(X)$ ?

While I am interested in this statement in general, I want it for a particular set $X$ that I describe below. Also it would be fine for me to make $\Gamma(X)$ the set of l.s.c. convex functions instead.

---

Here is a description of my particular $X$. Let $B$ be a complete Boolean algebra with the countable chain property, for any $x\in B$, let $X\triangleq S(B)$ be the set of [measure algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_algebra) $\mu$ on $B$ such that $\mu(1)=1$. The topology on $S(B)$ we consider is the coarsest such that for any $x\in B$, the mapping $\mu \to \mu(x)$ is continuous.

Any literature about such spaces would be most welcome, I don't have any starting point.

---

I am interested in this because I want to extend an increasing, (countably) linear functional from $\Gamma$ to $\mathbb R$ to a (countabley) linear functional from $\Gamma-\Gamma$ to $\mathbb R$ and then into a measure. This is related to what I attempt in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512658/show-the-existence-of-positive-linear-functional-whose-values-lies-in-given-inte). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456650/extending-a-function-that-gives-a-value-to-convex-functions-to-a-measure) that is related but on more general spaces.

Comment: The result is true for twice continuously differentiable maps for $X$ being compact subset of a normed space. For $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ one should be able to relax the differentiability requirement. Such type of functions  is call difference-of-convex functions or DC functions, and received a lot of attention from the viewpoint of optimization.

Comment: @daw Interesting. I think this is true for more functions than just those right ? In particular if $f$ is continuous and linear by part and bounded on $[0,1]$, then surely it is the sum of some scaled and shifted absolute values. Now for instance the indicator of a convex subset of $[0,1]$ is the limit of such piecewise functions and then a measurable funtion is the limit of simple functions so it feels like measurable functions are actually limits of such piecewise defined functions. I am wondering about a more general case in a more general space.

Comment: If someone has an idea of why I got a downvote and a close vote, I would be happy to try to fix the question.